# Cannot convert from 'System.collection.generic.List<bool> to

Tags: entity-framework-core

```
 var sections = await _context.EmpSec
                  .Select(sec => sec.EmpId == arg.empid).ToListAsync();
                  if (sections != null)
                      {
                          _context.EmpSec.RemoveRange(sections);

                      }
```

This throws error at design time "Cannot convert from 'System.Collection.Generic.List' to GR_API.Models.EF.EmpSec"

I tried sync and async both but have same error.

Comment: Use `Where` instead of `Select`. Make it a habit to look at intellisense info on methods you use.

Comment: Thsnk yu very much. I did that.